# Delete bottom two rows in Azure Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I would like to delete the bottom two rows of an excel file in ADF, but I don't know how to do it.
The flow I am thinking of is this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C3q6.png)
*I intend to filter -> delete the rows to be deleted in yellow.

The file has over 40,000 rows of data and is updated once a month. (The number of rows changes with each update, so the condition must be specified with a function.)

The contents of the file are also shown here.
The bottom two lines contain spaces and asterisks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyBYy.png)
Any help would be appreciated.
I'm new to Azure and having trouble.
I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a surrogate key transformation to put a row number on each row. Add a new branch to duplicate the stream and in that new branch, add an aggregate.

Use the aggregate transformation to find the max() value of the surrogate key counter.

Then subtract 2 from that max number and filter for just the rows up to that max-2.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
When filtering the bottom row and the second row from the bottom, can I use the max() function to select both of those rows at once?
Or do I need to split it into two steps, "delete bottom row" -> "delete bottom row (second from bottom) in remaining rows"?

Comment: The max() function must be used in an Aggregate transformation. I tried to provide an example here in Stack Overflow, but I didn't feel it was very clear. I'm going to put the answer solution into a post either on our docs or in a blog and then send that link to you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide a more detailed answer here ... I think I can get it in here without writing a separate blog.

The simplest way to filter out the final 2 rows is a pattern depicted in the screenshot here. Instead of the new branch, I just created 2 sources both pointing to the same data source. The 2nd stream is there just to get a row count and store it in a cached sink. For the aggregation expression I used this: "count(1)" as the row count aggregator.

In the first stream, that is the primary data processing stream, I add a Surrogate Key transformation so that I can have a row number for each row. I called my key column "sk".

Finally, set the Filter transformation to only allow rows with a row number <= the max row count from the cached sink minus 2.

The Filter expression looks like this: sk <= cachedSink#output().rowcount-2

[image]